# Exception in Thread Main. NullPointException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to do a push and pop operation on stack and trying to pop minimum element from stack. It is showing null pointer exception. I tried debugging it. But still it is throwing null point exception.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
public class Stacks {
        static void Stack_Push(Stack<Integer> SP, int a) 
        { 
            SP.push(new Integer(a)); 
            System.out.println("stack: " + SP); 
        } 

        static void stack_pop(Stack<Integer> SP) { 
            System.out.print("Popping Minimum Element ");
            int n = 0, k = 0;
            final int [] pop_array = null;
            while (!SP.empty()){
              int pop_elem = SP.pop();
              pop_array[k++] = pop_elem;
            }

            for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
              int j = i;
              int B = pop_array[i];
              while ((j > 0) && (pop_array[j-1] > B)) {
                  pop_array[j] = pop_array[j-1];
                  j--;
              }
              pop_array[j] = B;
            }
            System.out.println("stack: " + pop_array[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException { 
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>(); 
        int num, n;
        InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(ir);
        System.out.print("Enter number of elements : ");
        String str = bf.readLine();
        num = Integer.parseInt(str);
        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
              System.out.print("Enter elements : ");
          str = bf.readLine();
          n = Integer.parseInt(str);
          Stack_Push(st, n);
        } 

        stack_pop(st); 
        try { 
          stack_pop(st); 
        } 
            catch (EmptyStackException e) { 
          System.out.println("empty stack"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the exception itself, so that we know which line is throwing it.

Comment: bf.readLine might return null too

Answer (score 2):

In the `stack_pop` method, you're trying to affect value to a null array:

```
final int [] pop_array = null;
...
pop_array[k++] = pop_elem;
```

You should initialize it with the number of elements contained in your Stack.

There are other problems in this method too, like:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
```

where `n` is defined to 0 at the beginning and never changed.

And why are you calling two times `stack_pop(st)`? The second call will always be made with an empty stack. If it was to test if the exception is caught, the line

```
System.out.println("stack: " + pop_array[0]);
```

makes your program crash as your trying to access `pop_array[0]` whereas you initialized your array with the size of the stack, which was 0.

Answer (score 0):

In the code below, you are setting `pop_array` to `null` and then trying to work with it. This is your problem.

```
        final int [] pop_array = null;
        while (!SP.empty()){
          int pop_elem = SP.pop();
          pop_array[k++] = pop_elem;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize your pop_array:

```
final int [] pop_array = null;
```

Try this:

```
final int [] pop_array = new int[SP.size()];
```

Also you might need a guard around your sysout:

```
if (pop_array.length > 0) {
    System.out.println("stack: " + pop_array[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`pop_array` is not initialized at,

```
final int [] pop_array = null;
```

change it into,

```
final int [] pop_array = new int [SP.size()];
```